# Html element controlling height of its parent or sibling

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a two-column layout that adjusts to the browser window width automatically. One of the columns contains a dynamic content that can be short, but can be long, too. The other column always has text that is always the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                display: flex;
            }
            .left {
                flex: 1;
                background-color: cornflowerblue;
                overflow-y: auto;
            }
            .right {
                background-color: aquamarine;
                flex: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left">
Potentially<br>long<br>content<br>that<br>might<br>need<br>a<br>scrollbar<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5 Fusce pulvinar sit amet massa in vulputate. Cras eros ligula, condimentum non lacus nec, maximus lacinia orci.
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p>The text that<br>does not change<br>and must always<br>be displayed<br>in its entirety<br>without scrollbar.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod nibh ex, sit amet vulputate ipsum luctus non.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3Lhjza1/1/

I want to make a scrollbar to appear in the `.left` div whenever the height of its content is greater than the height of the content of the `.right` div. When the amount of text in the `.left` div is small, `.right` text should still be displayed without scroll bars (this is covered by flex already, but using flex is not a requirement):

[image: Short content example]
[image: Long content example]
[image: Wider screen example]

The obvious "solution" is to specify the max-height of the `.left` element to something "reasonable", but I need it to adjust automatically for different screen widths.

Is it possible to do (without javascript) or I am doomed to specifying fixed height for blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no way to affect a parent in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) (there is a [sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813465/css-sibling-selectors-select-all-siblings), although I don't see how would it be useful in this case), but this would be a way to do what you want, letting the `.right` div to determine the height of the container and the `.left` one adapting to it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container > * {
  padding: .2rem;
}
.container p {
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Potentially<br>long<br>content<br>that<br>might<br>need<br>a<br>scrollbar<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5 Fusce pulvinar sit amet massa in vulputate. Cras eros ligula, condimentum non lacus nec, maximus lacinia orci. Potentially<br>long<br>content<br>that<br>might<br>need<br>a<br>scrollbar<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5 Fusce pulvinar sit amet massa in vulputate. Cras eros ligula, condimentum non lacus nec, maximus lacinia orci. Potentially<br>long<br>content<br>that<br>might<br>need<br>a<br>scrollbar<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5 Fusce pulvinar sit amet massa in vulputate. Cras eros ligula, condimentum non lacus nec, maximus lacinia orci. Potentially<br>long<br>content<br>that<br>might<br>need<br>a<br>scrollbar<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5 Fusce pulvinar sit amet massa in vulputate. Cras eros ligula, condimentum non lacus nec, maximus lacinia orci.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>The text that<br>does not change<br>and must always<br>be displayed<br>in its entirety<br>without scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod nibh ex, sit amet vulputate ipsum luctus non.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, just came by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43352777/31782) that uses similar technique. I'll wait a bit before accepting for other suggestions, but it looks pretty good.

Comment: Damn right! I'd say you should put that as duplicate but maybe this, being a simpler case, would still be useful for someone