# Collapsing borders using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm having fun getting my head around the new CSS Grid spec, but I'm running into trouble with borders.

**Is it possible to collapse borders in a CSS Grid, or is there any way to style the gutter?**

As you can see in the snippet below, the `10px` borders stack (`20px` total) in-between blocks.

I understand this issue isn't unique to CSS Grids, but I'm hoping it'll allow for new solutions for creating a uniform 10px border between all boxes and on the outer edges.

My actual use-case is a calendar I'm making to practice working with Grids and React components. You can see the issue I'm running into here:

[image: CSS Grid Calendar].

Since every month is different, I'll have a lot of different edge-cases to consider.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 10px solid palegreen;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block first'>1</div>
  <div class='block'>2</div>
  <div class='block'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, here's a CSS Grid calendar somebody built: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276

Comment: Also, a common solution to the problem is to fill the empty cells with faded cells for the days from the previous and next month.

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B ! My plan is to make a super customizable calendar front-end so I can print out month calendars that look just how I like them. For now though, it's mostly about the learning exercise. Looking forward to reviewing that question and its answers; it looks like it'll be helpful.

Comment: It's remarkable that these modern ways to draw a grid still has shortcomings as fundamental as this. Compare this to table layouting from the dawn of HTML, with which one can just use `border-collapse: collapse`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You may use grid-gap and box-shadow:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
 box-shadow:0 0 0 10px palegreen;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block first'>1</div>
  <div class='block'>2</div>
  <div class='block'>3</div>
</div>
```

Or combine row and columns template setting:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 110px 110px;
  grid-template-rows:110px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
 border:solid 10px palegreen;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block first'>1</div>
  <div class='block'>2</div>
  <div class='block'>3</div>
</div>
```

Note that columns and rows of 120px will show both sides borders when box is set to 100px...

If `fr` value is used for columns, then do not set width on boxes (rows would follow same restriction).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 110px;
  /*whatever else */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 -10px 0 0;/* fixed width value missing */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: solid 10px palegreen;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block first'>1</div>
  <div class='block'>2</div>
  <div class='block'>3</div>
  <div class='block'>4</div>
  <div class='block'>5</div>
  <div class='block'>6</div>
  <div class='block'>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll be trying both of those for sure.

Comment: Do you think these approaches could still work if I've defined my grid template with `fr`s?

Comment: @TimFoley If you do, do not set width on children, only col number in the template *edit* added a snippet example

Comment: @TimFoley an exemple with 2 grids side by side and 1fr for rows and columns : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QvpBaO

Comment: Just tested it out, and I think you've solved it! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 34):

I just found a simple way to achieve this, using css `outline` instead of `border`.

The `outline` property draws a line outside the element, so, having 1px gap collapses both lines.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  gap: 1px; /* you can use gap instead of grid-gap */
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  outline: 1px solid darkgreen; /* Use outline instead of border */
}

.first {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block first'>1</div>
  <div class='block'>2</div>
  <div class='block'>3</div>
  <div class='block'>4</div>
  <div class='block'>5</div>
  <div class='block'>6</div>
</div>
```

As TylerH commented, outline does not take up space and can overlap, that is why you need to use the gap for it, if you want a 5px line, you should write 5px for both properties, the outline and the gap.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  outline: 5px solid darkgreen; /* The same width as the gap */
}
```

Comment: While outline draws a line outside the element, it's important to note it does not take up space, so it doesn't cause changes to the layout. This also allows a weird 'feature' where you can have two elements side by side and their outlines can appear to 'overlap'.

Comment: I found this answer to be the simplest and most universal solution. Thank you.

Comment: i thought this was the solution for me until i learned there's no `outline-top`, `outline-left`, etc :(

Comment: no need to set size for `.block`. also no need to set sizes for `.container`. this works too: `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)`

Comment: You'll particularly notice outline stacking when using transparency for the outline, making the outer and inner outlines appear different

Answer (score 13):

Consider controlling all sizing and spacing at the grid container level, not at the grid item level. Remove the borders and sizing applied to the items.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr)); /* 1 */ /* 2 */
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* 3 */
  grid-gap: 5px; /* 4 */
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.block {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

/* for demo only */
.block:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block'>0</div>
  <div class='block'>0</div>
  <div class='block'>1</div>
  <div class='block'>2</div>
  <div class='block'>3</div>
  <div class='block'>4</div>
  <div class='block'>5</div>
  <div class='block'>6</div>
  <div class='block'>7</div>
  <div class='block'>8</div>
  <div class='block'>9</div>
  <div class='block'>10</div>
  <div class='block'>11</div>
  <div class='block'>12</div>
  <div class='block'>13</div>
  <div class='block'>14</div>
  <div class='block'>15</div>
  <div class='block'>16</div>
  <div class='block'>17</div>
  <div class='block'>18</div>
  <div class='block'>19</div>
  <div class='block'>20</div>
  <div class='block'>21</div>
  <div class='block'>22</div>
  <div class='block'>23</div>
  <div class='block'>24</div>
  <div class='block'>25</div>
  <div class='block'>26</div>
  <div class='block'>27</div>
  <div class='block'>28</div>
  <div class='block'>29</div>
  <div class='block'>30</div>
  <div class='block'>31</div>  
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sejvLhru/5)

Notes:

1. `auto-fit`: Fill in as many columns as can fit on the row. Overflow columns will wrap.
2. `minmax()`: Each column will be a minimum width of 120px and maximum width of whatever free space is available. The `fr` unit is comparable to flex layout's `flex-grow` property.
3. `grid-auto-rows`: Automatically created rows (*implicit* rows) will be 100px in height.
4. `grid-gap`: 5px gutters all around. Shorthand for `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap`.

Comment: Nice! I'm hoping to have some more control over what happens with the unfilled space. I'll definitely keep this in mind for other applications.

Comment: I'm referring to the green background-color showing in the upper left and lower right.

Comment: Even though this does not let you control the `border-style` (which is a pity), this is probably the best solution for grid layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could take if you were ok with the gap border color being the same as the day cells that don't fall on the current month is to wrap a `div` around the entire grid container and set its `background-color` to the color you want your borders to be and give it 1px of `padding` with a `grid-gap` of 1px.  With this approach you're able to achieve a uniformly bordered grid without the complexity of using box-shadow, which feels like a hack to me.

Comment: Isn't that the same as @Michael_B's answer? Except that he uses 5px instead of 1px borders.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a pure CSS way to collapse the borders of a grid, but since I could find none, I made a little prototype.

[image: CSS Grid Collapsed Borders Rounded Corners]

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid" class="grid">
    <div class="element">1</div>
    <div class="element">2</div>
    <div class="element">3</div>
    <div class="element">4</div>
    <div class="element">5</div>
    <div class="element">6</div>
    <div class="element">7</div>
    <div class="element">8</div>
    <div class="element">9</div>
    <div class="element">10</div>
    <div class="element">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));  
}

.element {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.border-left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.border-top-left-rounded {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}

.border-top-right-rounded {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

.border-bottom-left-rounded {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

.border-bottom-right-rounded {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

**JS**

```js
function dynamicRoundedCorners() {
  // get
  const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
  const elements = grid.children;
  const gridStyle = getComputedStyle(grid);

  // reset
  for (element of elements) {
    element.classList = "";
    element.classList.add("element");
  }

  // analyze
  const elementsPerRowCount = gridStyle.gridTemplateColumns
    .split(" ")
    .filter((element) => Number(element.replace("px", ""))).length;
  const rowCount = Math.ceil(elements.length / elementsPerRowCount);
  const rowsFirstAndLastElements = [];
  let firstAndLastElementIndex = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    const rowFirstAndLastElements = [firstAndLastElementIndex];

    if (i === rowCount && rowCount > 1) {
      rowFirstAndLastElements.push(
        firstAndLastElementIndex + (elements.length % elementsPerRowCount) - 1
      );
    } else {
      rowFirstAndLastElements.push(
        firstAndLastElementIndex + elementsPerRowCount - 1
      );
    }
    rowsFirstAndLastElements.push(rowFirstAndLastElements);
    firstAndLastElementIndex += elementsPerRowCount;
  }

  // apply
  // -> add border-top on the first row
  for (let i = 0; i <= rowsFirstAndLastElements[0][1]; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.add("border-top");
  }

  // -> add border-left on every first element of a row
  for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    elements[rowsFirstAndLastElements[i][0]].classList.add("border-left");
  }

  // -> add top-left rounded corner on first element of first row
  elements[0].classList.add("border-top-left-rounded");
  // -> add top-right rounder corner on last element of first row
  elements[rowsFirstAndLastElements[0][1]].classList.add(
    "border-top-right-rounded"
  );
  // -> add bottom-left rounded corner on first element of last row
  elements[rowsFirstAndLastElements[rowCount - 1][0]].classList.add(
    "border-bottom-left-rounded"
  );
  // -> add bottom-right rounder corner on last element of last row
  elements[elements.length - 1].classList.add("border-bottom-right-rounded");
  // -> if elements.length % elementsPerRowCount != 0, add bottom-right rounder corner on last element of second to last row
  if (elements.length % elementsPerRowCount !== 0) {
    elements[
      rowsFirstAndLastElements[rowsFirstAndLastElements.length - 2][1]
    ].classList.add("border-bottom-right-rounded");
  }
}

// call
dynamicRoundedCorners();
window.addEventListener("resize", dynamicRoundedCorners);
```

Here is the link: https://codepen.io/RilDev/pen/gOmjNrQ