# div with 100% height and display: grid doesn't do what I expect

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My desired layout is a box center in the HTML body with 50% height (50vh) and width, with two equal width columns, and if the content in either column becomes larger than its own height, a vertical scrollbar is shown.

I have the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexanderbollbach/s5ygyvfw/4/).  The left column in the `display: grid` div has id `#col1`.  What I noticed is that if I set its height to `100%` then its height will grow to fit the text within it.

I don't understand why.  I'm saying that `#gridContainer` has a height of `100%` of its parent `#flexContainer`.  So shouldn't giving `#col1` a height of `100%` have it match its parent `#gridContainer`?

I notice that if I change `display: grid` to `display: block` in the `#gridContainer` selector, I will get the vertical scroll bars whether I give `#col1` the `height: 100%` rule or not.

Is this something to do with how css-grid interacts with the height css property that I'm not getting?

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: i say what i want in the first paragraph.  i can leave out 100% height in #col1 and that seems to have the effect i want, but I have no idea why that works.  so i want to know what is going on.

Comment: so you want to know that how that scrolling part has done ? in the first col...am I right

Comment: ...Can't you just apply `overflow: scroll;` to `#col2` as well? https://jsfiddle.net/mxubxpn7/

Comment: This is not really an issue of `height`. It's more an issue of `overflow`. Notice that if you disable `overflow` on `#col1`, the box stretches to full height, *with or without `height: 100%`*. https://jsfiddle.net/s5ygyvfw/7/

Comment: Here's the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276

Answer (score 0):

You have set a 50% parent height and under that, your col1 is having 50% height.
so your css

```
#col1 {
overflow: scroll;
width: 100%;
//height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
```

Your division has 50% height and you have used `overflow:scroll` so whenever the content size increases mor than 50% in compared to parent then the scroll bars appers. Thats all going on here.

Comment: If you want the second one to be the same just use ```overflow:scroll``` have a look on this : https://jsfiddle.net/mxubxpn7/

Comment: yes but uncomment the height: 100%.  if you do the scroll bar doesn't appear.  thats what i was confused about.

Comment: Is working with ```height: 200px;``` . I think that the div is taking the 100% of the whole body there may be some cause because you have used flex so it's just going out of the box

Comment: but i would have thought that 100% is of its parent div which is `#gridContainer`.  `#gridContainer` is 100% of its parent, `#flexContainer` which is `50vh`.  so thats why i'd think it should be 50% of the height of body.  somehow either the flex logic, or css-grid logic is overriding that assumption.  only i don't know enough to know which.

Comment: Basically, its better to give height to a parent div rather than the div you want to ```overflow``` because the overflow is taking the size as per the content inside...I mean 50% of the content size.

Comment: But the more chances are that you are using ```flex``` and that I feel is creating a problem just carry out your stuff in another way like using ```float``` or by using ```height``` as a permanent height. there are many ways.

Comment: isn't float outdated?