# Can grid items wrap?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, css-grid

How can I make the grid-items wrap inside their container? cause whenever input 64 as a new grid size the grid-items would overflow out of its container. I want the grid-items to adjust to the size of the grid-container.

So basically, I want the grid-container to remain its size no matter how many newly grid-item is added.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('#grid-container');

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    grid.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    grid.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    let tile = document.createElement('div');
    grid.appendChild(tile).className = 'grid-item';
    //fill color
    tile.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      tile.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    })
  }
}
makeGrid(16, 16);

function resizeGrid() {
  const resizeBtn = document.querySelector('#resize-btn');

  resizeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //remove default grid
    const gridItem = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
    gridItem.forEach((item) => {
      grid.removeChild(item);
    })
    //create new grid
    let input = prompt('number of tiles per side');
    let rows = input;
    let cols = rows;
    makeGrid(rows, cols);
  })
}

resizeGrid();
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-rows: 1;
  --grid-cols: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#resize-btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 10px solid coral;
  background-color: rgb(247, 208, 194);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="resize-btn">Resize</button>
  <div id="grid-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout adds columns and rows:

```
#grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr); 
   grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}
```

Columns and rows don't wrap. They append to the existing set of columns or rows.

Hence, grid items in this layout won't wrap. They occupy the cells created by the new tracks.

If you want a layout where the items wrap, use the grid `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` functions, which limit the creation of columns or rows to the size of the container. Working together, these functions and limits enable grid items to flow across tracks.

Another option is flexbox, which doesn't generate column or row tracks, just flex lines.

These posts may provide further guidance:

- [How to get grid items of different lengths to wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47082096/3597276)
- [Areas covered by Flexbox which are difficult or impossible to achieve with Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you create a div, there's a margin, border, padding and content areas to consider. In this case, if you set the padding to 1em, and want to display many divs, but they don't fit inside their container, that'll make increase the size of your container.

Just set margin and padding to zero, and use outline instead of border, which does not take extra space, so it won't make your container grow.

CSS

```
   .grid-item {
      outline: 1px solid blue;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

** By the way, if you want to place any content inside each div give it its own box-model properties you like and consider they take space.

Is this the result you were expecting?

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).