# CSS Grid with variable number of "auto" rows, but one row should take "1fr"

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm fiddling around with a CSS grid-based frontend and the following behaviour is required over and over and over again in different parts of the frontend:

1. A grid with a variable number of rows.
2. Every row should have a variable size (auto will do).
3. The last row should always take up all the remaining space.

So in the case I happen to need five rows, this does the trick:

```
.myGridForFiveRows
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto 1fr;
}
```

However, I'd really like a stylesheet that yields the correct behaviour for any given number of rows. I thought maybe I could somehow use `repeat()` to do this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

```
.myGrid
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, auto) 1fr;
}
```

I've been playing around with variants of `repeat(auto-fit, auto)` and `repeat(auto-fill, auto)`, which unfortunately aren't legit CSS, while `repeat(4, auto)` or `repeat(auto-fill, 30px)` are.

Any idea? It's not something I can't circumvent, but it just so happens that "display n properly sized rows, then let the last element take up all the remaining space" is basically the default behaviour for all elements in my spec...

Comment: What is the purpose of the last row? Perhaps a wrapper for the content and a "footer row" and solve the rest with flexbox or Grid?

Comment: Hey Paulie, the purpose of the last row is to contain a certain HTML element just like every other row. My employer just wants the last element to artificially blow up till it fills the rest of the page. I guess I could go down the route of specifying that if it's the last element of the grid, it should flex grow or whatever. I was just curious if you could tell the grid to do the sizing (which I find vastly prettier) as opposed to the content :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering your three requirements:

> 1. A grid with a variable number of rows.
> 2. Every row should have a variable size (auto will do).
> 3. The last row should always take up all the remaining space.

Flexbox is well-suited for the job. In fact, it may be the perfect fit (depending on your other requirements). I've provided a code sample below.

But if Grid Layout is what you want, then I think you're going to be disappointed. I don't believe [**Level 1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) can do the job.

The closest you can get would be:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 1px)) 1fr;
```

But it won't work because the current grid spec doesn't support this syntax.

### `repeat(auto-fit, auto) 1fr`

This is the code you tried. It's not valid because `auto` and `fr` cannot be used with `auto-fit`.

> [**7.2.2.1. Syntax of
>   `repeat()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax)
>
> Automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined
>   with **intrinsic** or **flexible** sizes.
>
> - An [**intrinsic**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#layout-algorithm) sizing function is `min-content`, `max-content`, `auto`, `fit-content()`.
> - A [**flexible**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#layout-algorithm) sizing function is `<flex>` (`fr`).

You can get around the `auto` limitation with something like this:

### `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 1px)) 1fr`

> [**`minmax(min,max)`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)
>
> Defines a size range greater than or equal to *min* and less than or
>   equal to *max*.
>
> If *max < min*, then *max* is ignored and `minmax(min,max)` is treated as *min*.
>
> As a maximum, a `<flex>` value sets the track’s flex factor; it is invalid as a minimum.

That works to properly auto-size your rows, whether the container has the default `auto` height or a `height` / `min-height` defined. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46Lhf5Lz/1/)

But it still doesn't solve the last row problem, since the `1fr` remains invalid, and causes the entire rule to fail. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46Lhf5Lz/4/)

Something like this would be valid:

### `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 1px)) 10em`

But the `auto-fit` doesn't work as you expect: the `10em` is applied to the second row. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46Lhf5Lz/2/)

And the rule doesn't work as expected if the container has a `height` or `min-height` defined. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46Lhf5Lz/3/)

---

Even with CSS Grid Layout now widely available, Flexbox is still the better choice in some cases.

This covers all your requirements with clean and simple code:

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

section:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

section {
  /* flex-basis: auto <-- this is a default setting */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>text text text</section>
  <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text </section>
  <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</section>
  <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</section>
  <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</section>
</article>
```

Comment: Also from §7.2.2.1: "The <auto-repeat> variant can repeat automatically to fill a space, but requires definite track sizes so that the number of repetitions can be calculated." This seems to be a limitation of grid layout.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes I saw that, but I figured the `1fr` could be factored in *after* the auto-repeat function had done its job. So I just left that out of my answer since I wasn't sure about the process.

Comment: Based on the OP's requirements (the 3 bullet points in the Q), flexbox should be fine.

Comment: I agree. Part of the craft is choosing the right tool for the job.

Comment: @BoltClock, I can understand why `1fr` may not work with `auto-fill`, since empty tracks don't collapse. So there's no free space left over. But with `auto-fit` empty tracks do collapse, and the last occupied track can have space to expand. More here if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227025/3597276

Comment: You're probably more familiar with grid layout than I am, but the only explanation I can think of is that the grid container doesn't know anything about its grid items in advance at the time it lays out its grid areas, so it doesn't know how many tracks it actually needs to create, and that is the reason for the limitation. (I was considering posting an answer along these lines, but I wanted to defer to you first.)

Comment: Hey folks, thanks for all the input. I will try to talk Michael_B's solution through with colleagues. Unfortunately there are quite a few things that the grid does for us (I left that out to produce a minimal example, sorry ...), but his solution might still be workable. Thanks again for everything!

Comment: I really just need to find time to sit down and *build* with flexbox and grid... just haven't had the chance to yet.

Answer (score -1):

This a little bit of a hack, but you could enter a very large number for the repeat that you would never cross over.  For example, you could do this for the grid-template-rows:

grid-template-rows: repeat(100000000, auto) 1fr;

I had the same issue, and this worked for me.