# CSS list with items size of min and max value

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Have a list with items. I would like the items to have min size of `200px` and `250px`. And if they cannot fit, so every item is `200px`, the list container wraps or item moves to the next row. When an item moves to the next row, it should have the same size as other items.

I have a very close implementation with `flex`. But when an item moves to the next row, it has a different size.

[Example](https://codepen.io/talgat-ruby/pen/yLwMpvN?editors=1100)

I tried: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));`. But it has no restriction of max `250px`.

With: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 250px));`. All items `250px` always.

Can I achieve it? With CSS-Grid, it should be achievable because the list has specific columns.

Comment: Perhaps with `clamp` but I'm not sure that is supported in `grid-template-columns`

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247124/css-grid-auto-fill-columns-with-static-minmax-values

Comment: @Paulie_D it does not support `clamp`. But thanks!