# How to utilize responsive images using CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid, responsive-images

Ive been working with the new CSS Grid Layout and one thing I can't seem to find much info on is how to make images responsive?? I've tried using media queries and setting the image width to 100% but the image still overflows outside of the grid. What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below  concept :

```js
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var allImages = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height =  getRandomSize(200, 400);
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/'+width+'/'+height+'" alt="pretty kitty">';
}

$('#photos').append(allImages);
```

```css
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="photos"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide imd default styles of `max-width:100%` and avoid using fixed width and height. Hope it is helpful to you.