# Nested CSS-grid implicitly fill remaining height from parent grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to have a child CSS-grid respect the dimensions of the parent grid. How would I be able to achieve that?

I was initially writing something like this:

```css
.site,
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav' 'child';
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.child {
  grid-area: child;
}

.child-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'test';
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: test;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="nav">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-grid">
      <div class="content">
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have 'content' be a scrollable area that doesn't expand the height of the parent (so it should be '270px').

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The grid item (`.child`) is given `min-height: auto` by default. Apply `min-height: 0` to `.child` to overrule this.

Then add `height: 100%` to `.child-grid` and `overflow: auto` to `content`...

```css
.site,
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav' 'child';
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.child {
  grid-area: child;
  min-height: 0;
}

.child-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'test';
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: test;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="nav">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-grid">
      <div class="content">
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Michael_B's answer was informative but this more specific set of rules was what worked for me. My fault for not being clearer with my example. It's more like "parent-grid-areas: 'navbar' 'content'"  and "content-grid-areas: 'itemlist map'" where itemlist is scrollable. Thanks

Comment: Sir, why min-height auto affects parent grid? Can you explain why this is happened?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a quick and simple solution with no changes to your HTML. Just add this to your code:

```
.child { 
   overflow: auto;
}
```

This overrides the `min-height: auto` default setting on grid items, allowing them to shrink below the size of their content and create overflow conditions.

Full explanation here: [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276)

```css
.site,
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav' 'child';
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.child {
  grid-area: child;
  overflow: auto;   /* NEW */
}

.child-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'test';
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: test;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="nav">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-grid">
      <div class="content">
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
        <div>blah</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, instead of what you have here:

```
.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;
}
```

Try this:

```
.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 270px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I also removed an extra container (`.child-grid`) which doesn't appear to be necessary.

```css
.site,
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 270px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav' 'child';
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.child {
  grid-area: child;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-grid">
  <div class="nav">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
      <div>blah</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool + 1... Do you know why `overflow: auto` works by itself, but `min-height: 0` requires additional rules on the contents of `.child`?

Comment: In terms of the `min-height: auto` default on grid (and flex) items, it can be overridden with `min-height: 0` or `overflow` with any value other than `visible`. Overriding with `min-height`, however, doesn't launch scrollbars. See my answer in the link reference I posted (and see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/3597276) too, which goes into more detail).

Answer (score 0):

**Well, give a dedicated height to your child grid:**

```
height: 240px;
```

**and set**

```
overflow: auto;
```

So, indeed, height is ensured. And if necessary, scrollbars will appear.
Not sure, if the fairly recent feature of css grids is really the best thing to use here. You may want to have a look at flexbox: https://codepen.io/fnocke/details/RxMKOK

Or –even more compatible– you could indeed stick with normal `display: block;`. As long as you specify heights and set the overflow, that should do as well.