# Why does minmax(0, 1fr) work for long elements while 1fr doesn't?

Tags: css, css-grid

So I have this grid:

```
+---------+------------------------------+---------+    
|  <div>  |  <p> - 1000 characters long  |  <div>  |
+---------+------------------------------+---------+
```

Inside `p` there's super long string with no spaces. `div`s are placeholders with fixed dimensions.
This produces the above:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
```

But changing `minmax(0, 1fr)` to `1fr` gives this:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------+    
|  <div>  |               <p> - 1000 characters long  |  <div>  |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

It overflows out of its parent and way out of screen size. Why isn't it behaving like minmax?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPQZGB)

Comment: Another relevant syntax I found: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));` ... see here: https://chenhuijing.com/blog/the-horizontal-overflow-problem/

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Because `1fr` is equivalent to `minmax(auto, 1fr)`, by default.

When you use `minmax(0, 1fr)`, that's something different than standalone  `1fr`.

In the first case, the track cannot be smaller than the size of the grid item (*min* size is `auto`).

In the second case, the track is free to resize to a 0 width/height.

More details:

- [Reconsider the meaning of `1fr`](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1777)
- [Prevent grid area from expanding causing whole page to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52785750/3597276)

Comment: Thank you! How odd to think that the minimum value of `auto` can actually exceed the maximum value of `1fr` in the case of `minmax(auto, 1fr)`.