# Css grid auto sized row content with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I've been having problems with implementing a nested grid structure. 
This is a simplified example. As you can see the nested structure gives the height for the outer structure, thus growing outside the body.
What I'd like to achieve is to make the `.content__inner` element, and **only** that element scrollable. Everything else should be inside the viewport. How can I achieve that?

**Edit 1:**
Just to clarify, I'm using 100vh on the body, but don't want to set it on the container. The container should have the height of its parent, whatever it is.

```css
body {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "side content" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content minmax(min-content, max-content) min-content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}

.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-item {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="container container__inner">
      <div class="header header__inner">header</div>
      <div class="side side__inner">side</div>
      <div class="content content__inner overflow">
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer footer__inner">footer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also made a jsfiddle examle for this https://jsfiddle.net/bgolyoo/ezd2usoh/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is easy to describe, but may not have a simple solution (depending on your requirements).

The problem is actually clear to see in the title itself:

> Css grid auto sized row content with overflow

Auto-sized elements cannot overflow. They are **auto sized**. This means the element shrinks and expands based on its content size, never having a need to overflow.

There has to be something that sets a fixed length on the container. A boundary that can be crossed, thus triggering an overflow condition.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):*

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

Your row heights are insufficient to trigger an overflow:

```
grid-template-rows: min-content minmax(min-content, max-content) min-content
```

But something like this would work:

```
  grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%
```

Unfortunately, the code above only works in Chrome. For the layout to also work in Firefox and Edge, do this:

```
  grid-template-rows: 10% minmax(0, 80%) 10%
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "side content" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 10% minmax(0, 80%) 10%; /* adjustment */
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}

.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-item {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container container__inner">
      <div class="header header__inner">header</div>
      <div class="side side__inner">side</div>
      <div class="content content__inner overflow">
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer footer__inner">footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Basically, you need to find some way to set a fixed height limit on the overflow row for the scrollbar to function.

---

For an explanation of the browser differences described above see these posts:

- [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276)
- [How come minmax(0, 1fr) works for long elements while 1fr doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52861086/3597276)

Comment: Thank you, I like your answer the most. I think I was going about this whole thing wrong, and this answer shows where. I will try to set some explicit height for the overflow container, though I was hoping for it to be auto sized with the available space left.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant by wanting it to be scrollable, here is my solution,

I changed the `max-height` to `100vh`, which will fix the `.container` class's height to the height of the screen

I added `overflow: scroll` to make the any content exceeds the class `.container` height scrollable

```
.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;


  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "side content" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content minmax(min-content, max-content) min-content;
}
```

Comment: I think I need to specify some things. So the example uses 100vh on the body, but I don't want to set that on the container. Also as I stated, I'd like the whole structure to be in the viewport, and only the inner content with class content__inner to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain space of header and footer from layout of `100vh` than your `.content__inner` fit as `100vh`... let me explaining you with add one line to your code. [edited code](https://jsfiddle.net/24xmLsdo/)

i've added below code to your code

`.content__inner {
   max-height: calc(100vh - 96px); /* added max height */
}`

so container have the height of its parent, whatever and it's but never goes our of `100vh` and fix as your requirement of scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="container container__inner">
      <div class="header header__inner">header</div>
      <div class="side side__inner">side</div>
      <div class="content-mod">
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer footer__inner">footer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

your Css file:

```
body {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "side content" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content minmax(min-content, max-content) min-content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 74px);
}

.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-item {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

I hope this works for you. :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

display: grid;
grid-template-columns: max-content auto;

<div>some title</div>
<div className="flex">some description</div>
```