# Why is minmax(auto, 1fr) track different from auto if content is longer than 1fr?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an issue with CSS Grid in my app while using `minmax` function, and that codepen demonstrates it:

https://codepen.io/dragonflypl/pen/eYNxmrB

In general: AFAIR `minmax` ignores max value, if min value is bigger than max. So for:

```
grid-template-columns: auto minmax(auto, 1fr) 1fr 1fr;
```

if content in the second column is really large, then it should take `auto` and grow the column. However, it does not work like this.

But... In the example that has:

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr 1fr;
```

it works as expected. Both `auto` columns grow and seem to share their piece of space equally.

So it looks like having `minmax` function, delays the computation of the track size.

Is there any technical explanation for it?

```css
.grid-one {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(auto, 1fr) 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-two {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-one>div,
.grid-two>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-one">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident velit minus reprehenderit rem rerum, impedit consequuntur fuga inventore est hic nisi placeat non unde sapiente quia blanditiis! Repudiandae, provident incidunt!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ratione ducimus ipsa impedit in iste cum? Odio possimus porro placeat! Quo similique exercitationem eligendi, numquam fuga voluptas doloribus amet aliquam!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis tenetur iste, quibusdam numquam sunt quod libero consequuntur nesciunt, laboriosam aperiam, fugit accusantium veritatis sequi? Aspernatur delectus dolorum minus laborum repellendus.</div>
  <div>a</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-two">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident velit minus reprehenderit rem rerum, impedit consequuntur fuga inventore est hic nisi placeat non unde sapiente quia blanditiis! Repudiandae, provident incidunt!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ratione ducimus ipsa impedit in iste cum? Odio possimus porro placeat! Quo similique exercitationem eligendi, numquam fuga voluptas doloribus amet aliquam!</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis tenetur iste, quibusdam numquam sunt quod libero consequuntur nesciunt, laboriosam aperiam, fugit accusantium veritatis sequi? Aspernatur delectus dolorum minus laborum repellendus.</div>
  <div>a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `minmax(auto, 1fr)` is the same as `1fr` so your first example is `auto 1fr 1fr 1fr` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52861514/8620333

Comment: Also, `fr` units are not actual lengths. So your point about... `if min > max, then max is ignored`... doesn't apply here, because `fr` units are only distributions of free space (and these distributions occur after all actual lengths are calculated). https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#fr-unit