# Why doesn't `width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: contain;` make a <video> fit its container?

Tags: html, css, video, css-grid, object-fit

So I have a page with a grid layout, with a header and a footer and a black content container in the middle.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr max-content;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.videoContainer {
  background-color: black;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>This is the header</div>
  <div class="videoContainer">
  </div>
  <div>This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

So far so good.

Now I want to put a video that will stretch to fit this container (and be centered). Here's attempt with `object-fit: contain;`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr max-content;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.videoContainer {
  background-color: black;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>This is the header</div>
  <div class="videoContainer">
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div>This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Instead of fitting the video to the container, the container expands to fit the video.

How can I keep the container at its inherent dimensions and make the video fit its container?

Comment: You never gave your `videoContainer` any `max-height` or `height`.

Comment: @YongPin It's `1fr` from the `grid-template-rows`, so it's supposed to be everything in the middle of the page between the header and footer. But even if I give `.videoContainer` a `height: 100%` the problem is the same.

Comment: First thing you need to know is that `1fr` is equivalent to `minmax(auto, 1fr)`, meaning that the container won't be smaller than its content, by default. So, start by replacing `1fr` with `minmax(0, 1fr)`. That will solve the overflow problem. [revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fr5c8w6u/) | [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52861086/3597276)

Comment: change the unit to something static, e.g. `90vh`

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Aha! Thanks, can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `1fr`

The first thing you need to know is that `1fr` is equivalent to `minmax(auto, 1fr)`, meaning that the container won't be smaller than its content, by default.

So, start by replacing `1fr` with `minmax(0, 1fr)`. That will solve the overflow problem.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: max-content minmax(0, 1fr) max-content;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.videoContainer {
  background-color: black;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>This is the header</div>
  <div class="videoContainer">
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div>This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

- Reference: [Why does minmax(0, 1fr) work for long elements while 1fr doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52861086/3597276)

---

### `object-fit`

If you want the video to actually "fit this container" (as in cover the full width and height), then try `object-fit: cover` as opposed to `contain`.