# Understanding overflow / minmax behaviour in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

TLDR: [Codepen of nested grid overflowing](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/abqrNyr) and not being fixed by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0,1fr));`

---

So I've an element `container`, with two main elements, `summary-wrapper` and `stats-wrapper`

`container` has the following grid:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);

    column-gap: 4rem;
    row-gap: 4rem;
    padding: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

`summary-wrapper` is placed at `grid-column: 1/11;` (line 96) and
`stats-wrapper` at `grid-column: 11/17;` (line 25)

In my mind, changing the grid column of the stats-wrapper to `grid-column: 12/17` should just move the start of the element, which it does in Chrome:

Chrome (no overflow):

[image: chrome grid-column change]

But in Firefox:

[image: Firefox grid-column change]

Now the behaviour being different between browsers seems a bit weird, but doesn't really change the fact that my mental model for how grid containers works is just... wrong - and I've experienced (and am experiencing in my project) this behaviour in Chrome, so that's not really the focus of my question.

I've had this issue before, but with inputs, and was directed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52861514/7396516) that allows longer elements to collapse using `grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0,1fr));`

This seems to work for the stats element (if you look the header no longer overflows the page). But because the contents of that element (excluding the header) are part of a nested grid too, I get the same problem, but it's not fixed using `grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0,1fr));` (line 50) this time:

[image: Firefox grid-column nested problem]

I just find it very strange, as I can't see any reason why the elements (in either case) *need* to overflow. Even the fix using `minmax(0,1fr)` relies on the explanation that

> 1fr is equivalent to minmax(auto, 1fr)

and that `auto` is preventing the track being smaller than the item. But in this case (afaik) the items `stats__section--viewed` `stats__section--applications` and `stats__section--trend` *have no min size*, other than their text

I'm just stumped!

[codepen](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/abqrNyr)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the overflow is a `column-gap` rule in the nested grid `.stats__content`.

```
.stats__content {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr));
  column-gap: 4rem; <----- CULPRIT
  row-gap: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2rem 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem;
}
```

Being that it's a fixed width, repeated 15 times (because gaps only go between tracks, not between tracks and container edges), an overflow is inevitable in this case.

```
(4rem) * (15 gaps) = 60rem of inflexible width
```

Reduce the number of gaps or find another solution for separating the items.

Comment: Ah, great, I hadn't considered that at all. Is it just something you have to watch out for/judge by eye? (ie if I want more control over positioning I just have to reduce the size of the gutters or use margins?) Thanks for the help though

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, fixed widths impact the size of an element. Fixed widths applied to gutters are no exception.