# How to make a section grow to wrap content in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How does one get a `<section></section>` to grow to fit its content with CSS Grid layout?

[image: screenshot of page]

The dark blue section on the right should end where the yellow highlight is. In other words, it should wrap around its content. I'm not sure how I can get it to do that.

I have created [a Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/ejJgGN?editors=1100).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="deity-details">
  <header>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
      <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="breadcrumb__item">Home</a> /
      <a href="#" class="breadcrumb__item">Deities</a> /
      <a asp-controller="Deity" asp-action="Details" asp-route-slug="@Model.Slug" class="breadcrumb__item">@Model.Name</a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="deity-name h1__white">@Model.Name</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="deity-description">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
  </section>

  <section class="deity-meta">
    <div class="attributes">
      <div class="attribute">
        <label class="attribute-label">Origin</label>
        <h4 class="attribute-value">@Model.Origin</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="attribute">
        <label class="attribute-label">Aliases</label>
        <h4 class="attribute-value">@Model.Aliases</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="attribute">
        <label class="attribute-label">Sex</label>
        <h4 class="attribute-value">@Model.Sex</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

And here's the SCSS:

```
.deity-details {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 / span 10;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
  background: $dark-navy;
}

.breadcrumbs,
.deity-name {
  grid-column: 3 / span 6;
}

.breadcrumbs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: $white;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif;
}

.breadcrumb__item {
  color: $white;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.breadcrumb__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.deity-name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.deity-description {
  grid-column: 3 / span 3;
  grid-row: 3 / span 8;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.deity-meta {
  grid-column: 7 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3 / span 6;
  background: $dark-navy;
  border-bottom-left-radius: $border-radius;
  border-bottom-right-radius: $border-radius;
  padding: 30px 50px 0 50px;
}

.attribute {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid $light-blue;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.attribute:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.attribute-label {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Abel", sans-serif;
  color: $light-blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.attribute-value {
  color: $white;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  line-height: 4rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strong hint to the answer may be in the question itself.

> How to make a section grow to wrap content in CSS Grid?

You're asking how to adjust for content size. That usually involves `auto` sizing.

In your code you set the row sizes using `fr` units:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr)
```

The `fr` unit has no direct association with content. It factors in only free space.

If you want a track to factor in content size, then use `auto` or `min-content` instead.

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(10, min-content)
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLpWON?editors=1100)

Comment: Hi Michael_B, any thoughts about this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962136/grid-element-height-not-setting ? I don't know if you already saw it.

Comment: Tricky. Here are some thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011140/3597276 @TemaniAfif