# Flow:Column Flexbox breaks inside display:grid Container

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to integrate a layout like this one https://jsfiddle.net/przemcio/xLhLuzf9/3/ inside of a larger CSS grid layout. However, it all breaks as soon as a container has the property `display: grid`. By "breaks", I mean that the desired flexbox shrinking properties of the `.content` div does not apply, and it does not shrink and allow the footer's content to show above the scroll fold.

This is a barebones demo, but in my bigger app there's the same behavior. Why does CSS Grid break this kind of layout, even inside of a child cell, and how can I fix it?

Demo:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.grid {
  /* this line breaks it: */
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cell {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          <p><b>footer</b>
            <br>
            <br>(sized to content)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify `height:100%` to the grid item as it will create [an unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51962136/8620333). Then you should hide the overflow or enable the scroll.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.grid {
  /* this line breaks it: */
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cell {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  overflow:auto;
  /*display: block; not needed*/
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          <p><b>footer</b>
            <br>
            <br>(sized to content)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can also keep `height:100%` and specify `100vh` within the rows template. In the this case, the percentage height will behave as intended:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.grid {
  /* this line breaks it: */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:100vh;
}

.cell {
  height: 100%;
  /*display: block; not needed*/
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
          <p>
            <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          <p><b>footer</b>
            <br>
            <br>(sized to content)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! For anyone interested, my fix was related to my use of https://github.com/azz/styled-css-grid. Rather than explicitly specifying the `rows` property in the `Grid` element (I was using some weird setting that wasn't necessary), I let it use the defaults, which magically fixed everything.

Comment: Follow up note: if you have more than 1 row, for this row in particular, setting its track height to `minmax(0px, auto)` somehow does the trick (and simply `auto` doesn't).