# Height 100% inside flex item

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a layout that is mainly divided into 3 parts and the middle one should take a full height. And it does.

However, I need an additional `div` which will play a role of the backdrop and here the problem comes. The child doesn't want to take 100% height.

Here `.body` is a div that is being stretched when there is not enough content and `.bg-gray` is the one I want to take its parent full height.

Is there a way achieve this **without** using relative + absolute positioning?

Also, I'm looking for the answer to my question: why is this happening that way.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #aaa444;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="header">
 
  </div>
  
  <div class="body">

    <div class="bg-gray">
      <div>
        asdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="footer">
 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: if you change min-height by height (inside .container) it will work, here is the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700510/behavior-with-height-minheight-and-displayflex/56701229#56701229

Comment: Keep flexing...it's not inherited.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it doesn't change anything. either `height` or `min-height` no difference

Comment: if you change the min-height of the container to height (not the min-height of the element)

Answer (score 0):

Apply flexbox to the `.body` div.

```
.body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #aaa444;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.bg-gray div {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">

  </div>

  <div class="body">

    <div class="bg-gray">
      <div>
        asdasd
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but that is inappropriate because it breaks my other layout :) I've started my tries from that

Comment: with giving .body to display flex its take full height as you told in your question let us know about your other layout so we can fix that is any break in your other layout