# Double height of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something that I assumed would be quite simple. In the below code, I want to make the parent height 200% of its current height, which is based on its children. The reason for this is that I can then position the children within the parent as I wish. Is there any way to simply double the height of the parent div?

HTML

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200% // Does not work
}
```

Comment: Sure, find out what height is currently set (e.g. 500px) and double it in .parent (so new height would be 1000px).

Comment: 200% is a valid value but this would mean that your element with the class of .parent should also be a child of another element with a specified height.... maybe provide a bit more context

Comment: Hi @LFX - sorry I should have stated I don't want to specify heights anywhere, I just want to expand as per the content of the children.

Comment: can you give more context on your real use case? I am pretty sure we can do what you want easily

Comment: @TemaniAfif Use case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956427/height-of-parent-to-be-double-that-of-child?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi Paulie. Yes that thread is a duplicate, but I wanted to simplify the question in this thread. The other question is my real-world usage though, for additional context.

Comment: in the example code you have the height of event elements also set to a percentage... is there a reason why you don't have a fixed height for these elements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is *hack* using CSS grid. In the below code the `span` element will have twice the height of its content but you will also have an overflow:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200%;
  border: 2px solid;
}

span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis lobortis lectus, a tincidunt sem. Morbi aliquet est sit amet justo vestibulum sodales.</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</span>
</div>
```

Detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137966/8620333

Comment: Also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout

Comment: @Paulie_D I guess it deserve an answer better than my hack. I forgot about the `1fr`