# Equalize two columns using their width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got three photos, which are arranged in two columns :

- The left column contains 1 photo, which is a portrait (width < height)
- The right columns contains 2 photos of the exact same size, which are landascapes (width > height)

I would like to make the two columns equal in term of height, such as the height of the left column is equal of the height of the right column.

Since I cannot crop the photos, I have to use the width of columns to make them equal height (which means they are not 50%/50%).

You can see an example here:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x900" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x400" alt="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x400" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the associated CSS:

```css
img {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  max-width: 100%
}

.container {
  width: 700px; /* Container width is fixed */
  display: flex;
}

.left {
   width: 52%; /* I want to change this */
   margin-right: 16px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/9f2gom0q/

At the moment, the only solution I found was to manually fix the width of one of the columns, which does sound right and may broke the grid if the photos change.

Does flex-based solution exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using CSS grid:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

.left {
  grid-row: span 2;
  height: 100%;
  
  animation:h 10s  infinite;
}


/* A hack to force the correct rendring*/
@keyframes h{
 from {
  height:99.9%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/400x900" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x400" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x400" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! But can you explain me where that hack come from and what is it purpose?

Comment: @MathieuBour the purpose of this hack is to force the calculation of the height correctly. percentage height are sometimes tricky. By the way, this works fine on Chrome, firefox is giving bad result. Will try to find a solution

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will search too. Do you have any reference for this bug?

Comment: @MathieuBour it's not really a bug but a complex behavior related to percentage value and not all the browser handle it the same way. basically using percentage need a reference and here it's the grid track and the height of the grid track is defined by the content so we have a kind of cycle. Here is an answer where I am explaining an example of such behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137966/8620333

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to make the two columns equal in term of height

In flexbox, columns are already the same height by default. It’s just that visually they look different to you.

1) Do not forget about "height: 100%" for "img"

2) Instead of a "margin-bottom: 15px;" for "img" is better to use

```
img + img {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

3) It is bad idea to use `<img>` as flex-element. It is better to wrap in into addition `<div>`

**Result:**

https://jsfiddle.net/wuzgvkp3/1/

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin: 7.5px;
}

.col--right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.col--right .item {
  height: calc(50% - 7.5px);
}

.col--right .item+.item {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col col--left">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/400x900" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col--right">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x400" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: That's work, but as you can see, photos are streched, which is not desirable in my case...