# Why's CSS percentage (%) height applied to grand-child of flex element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to check how CSS 100% height property works. But there's one thing I can't understand.

Why's 100% height working perfectly on `.flex-grand-child` (Chrome)? Does `.flex-child` have height property? So why it's even working???

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Casomniac/hx7u1sr2/)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-parent {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
    width: 300px;
}

.flex-grand-child {
   height: 100%;
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-parent">
        <div class="flex-child">
          <div class='flex-grand-child'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular case where the browser can handle percentage value on height due to the stretch effect of flexbox. The `flex-child` has a default alignment equal to stretch which is equivalent to having `height:100%` then the `flex-parent` is also filling its parent height with `flex-grow:1`. At the end, the browser was able to correctly resolve the `height:100%` of `flex-grand-child`

> If the flex item has `align-self: stretch`, redo layout for its contents, treating this used size as its definite cross size so **that percentage-sized children can be resolved.**<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-stretch)</sup>

If you disable the stretch alignment, it will break:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-parent {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  align-self: flex-start; /*this will break it*/
  border: 1px solid;
}

.flex-grand-child {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child">
      <div class='flex-grand-child'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To use simple words: When having the stretch effect, the browser will first define the parent height based on its own parent (the content play no role here) then the browser will make the content `height:100%` of the previous calculated height. Without stretch the browser need to consider the content to define the height of the parent and here we will fall into the classic issue of percentage height.

---

Related question to get more cases where percentage can be resolved without having an explicit height defined on the parent element: [Why is my Grid element's height not being calculated correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137966/8620333)

Here is the relevant part of the specification dealing with this: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#percentage-sizing

It's a bit complex but it's different from [the CSS2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) where percentage will always fail if the parent height is not specified:

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

Answer (score 0):

The `.flex-parent` element has `flex-grow: 1` applied, giving it the full height of the `.container` (`height: 100%`). It also has `display: flex` applied, making it a flex container.

This latter setting automatically triggers `align-items: stretch`, which causes the flex item – `.flex-child` – to expand the full height of the container. So the `.flex-child` computes to `height: 100%`.

Modern browsers, now accepting flex heights as a reference point for children with percentage heights, set the child of the flex item – `.flex-grand-child` – to the full height of the parent, which is `height: 100%`.

More details here: [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Answer (score -2):

You have .container as a flex container with a `flex-direction` of column, so by default, the child element will stretch to fill. So `.flex-parent` is stretching to fill `.container`.

Since `.flex-parent` is also a flex-container, `.flex-child` is stretching to fill that.

Finally, since `.flex-grand-child` has height 100%, it is also filling the entire area.