# Why does `height: 100%` value 'work' for child tags of grid-items?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Consider this:

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-item > p {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container" style="display: grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>I am p.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
    <p>I am p.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
    <p>I am p.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
    <p>I am p.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because of the CSS line:

```css
    .grid-item > p {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

The `p` tags have the same height as the grid-items. This is great, as this is what I want. My question is, how is this working?

I thought that if the parent element/containing-block's `height` wasn't specified explicitly (surely grid-items, here, have `height: auto;`) then `%` (on the child element) won't work (and something like `height: auto` will be used instead).

Additionally, I know/think that if the parent is absolutely positioned, `%` will work (return a percentage value of what parent's actual `height` is).

What is making `%` work for children of grid-items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the `stretch` default alignment of grid item.

> Note: Since formulas calculated using only definite sizes, such as the stretch fit formula, are also definite, **the size of a grid item which is stretched is also considered definite**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#algo-overview)</sup>

As you can see, the size is definite so it can be used as reference for percentage.

---

Same logic for flexbox:

> If the flex item has align-self: stretch, redo layout for its contents, treating this used size **as its definite cross size so that percentage-sized children can be resolved** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-stretch)</sup>

Related question with non-intuive percentage behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137966/8620333