# CSS height mysteries: Different on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/jth42/pen/BaQZeoq) looks different on Chrome than on Firefox. The html and css is:

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>header</div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="central">central</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  min-height: 200px;
  
  background: lightsalmon;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.central {
  /*height: 98%;*/
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

On Chrome, even though the central element's height is always relative to the intermediate elements actual height (when placed with grid or when using a percentage height like the one in comments), but only if is *grandparent's* height was explicitly set (and even though *that* height is not what the central element's is calculated in relation to).

(Grid layout seems to have no such issue: If you change the outer element's display from flex to grid it works on Chrome too.)

Is this a bug or is the behaviour not clearly enough defined?

I can't say I understand that I understand's Mozilla's formal definition of percentage heights on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) anyway and I don't know if there's a more rigorous definition.

Comment: Firefox is the correct one here since by default we should have a stretch alignment for grid items

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65116080/8620333