# Percentage 'min-height' works only when element has indirect parent with 'display: flex'

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, percentage

Cannot understand why `#inner` element has its height only when `#main` got `display:flex` rule.

Here is my code:

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: violet
}

.content {
  font-size: 2em
}

#inner {
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove `display: flex` rule height of `#inner` equals to 0:

```css
#main {
/*   display: flex */
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: violet
}

.content {
  font-size: 2em
}

#inner {
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And one more thing.
When `#inner` has some content inside, its height is summed up to `#main` height.

[Take a look to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCf5p.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing the result of the `stretch` alignment related to flexbox. by default flex items are stretched so the following apply:

> If the flex item has `align-self: stretch`, redo layout for its contents, treating this used size as **its definite** cross size so **that percentage-sized children can be resolved**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-stretch)</sup>

For this reason, `min-height` with percentage is working. If you change the alignment and keep `display:flex`, it won't work

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: violet;
  align-self:flex-start;
}

.content {
  font-size: 2em
}

#inner {
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should also note that you are having an overflow in your first example because the percentage is related to the content so anything you will add is more than the content itself.

Add border to notice this

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: violet;
  border:5px solid red;
}

.content {
  font-size: 2em
}

#inner {
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div class="content">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A similar behavior happen in CSS Grid as well: [Why does `height: 100%` value 'work' for child tags of grid-items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65115888/8620333)