# Irregular child width error with CSS grid layout in Firefox

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to build equal columns for my cards, but my solution is not working in Firefox while it does in Chrome.

My code:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 1170px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 15px;
    @include breakpoint(xs) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
    @include breakpoint(sm) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
    @include breakpoint(lg) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    }
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Chrome result (good):

[image]

Firefox result (bad):

[image]

Comment: maybe it's this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276 (but can't know for sure because there isn't enough code in the question to reproduce the problem)

Comment: It's not working. I tried with percentatges and it works, but I would prefer to work with fractions instead of percentatges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the following CSS?

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Your code seems to work for me. Maybe it's a html-element inside your card that's different?

Could you make a pen with the full code (`HTML` & `CSS`) so we would be able to help better?

Could you try prefixing your entire css?

Comment: I finally found the problem, a js generated html-element inside my grid.

Comment: Great to hear! Please upvote if I was any help at all. :)