# Why column width is broken?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I have table with grid layout. But when width is reduced not all columns have same width. Here `Кількість` is spanned over two 2fr columns. So I expect it has same width as two column: `1` and `грн`. The [source code](https://codepen.io/KES777/pen/gdGpWe)

```css
/* The layout for invoice items */
.items-grid {
  width: 680px;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 60% 2fr 2fr 3fr 3fr;
 grid-template-rows: auto;
 border: 3px solid black;
}

/* All cells should be aligned vertically by center */
.items-grid > dt {
 display: grid;
 align-items: center;
}

/* Do not display right/bottom border for last column/row */
.items-grid > dt:not(:nth-child(7n)) {
 border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.items-grid > dt:not(:nth-last-child(-n+7)) {
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}


/* N, Code */
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(7n +1),
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(7n +2)
{
 justify-items: center;
}

/* Qty, Price, Suma */
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(7n +4),
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(7n +6),
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(7n +7)
{
 justify-items: end;
}


/** STYLING FIRST LINE **/
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(-n+7) {
 font-weight: bold;
 justify-items: center;
 text-align: center;
}

/* 'Quantity' column is splitted by two later */
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(4) {
 grid-column-start: span 2;
}

/* added for parity cell should be hidded */
.items-grid > dt:nth-child(5) {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<dl class="items-grid">
  <dt>№
  <dt>Код
  <dt>Товари (роботи, послуги)
  <dt>Кіль<wbr>кість
  <dt>
  <dt>Ціна з ПДВ
  <dt>Сума з ПДВ
  <dt>1
  <dt>MED000754
  <dt>Надання в строкове платне користування Віртуальної інфраструктури (TuchaBit)
  <dt>1
  <dt>грн
  <dt>630,62
  <dt>630,62
  <dt>2
  <dt>MED000754
  <dt>Надання в строкове платне користування Віртуальної інфраструктури (TuchaBit)
  <dt>1
  <dt>грн
  <dt>630,62
  <dt>630,62
</dl>
```

[image]

**UPD**
This is broken only in FF

Comment: i've tested on FF61 and works fine

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `<dt>`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaryZg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items)

Comment: @Michael_B: When I do that. The text will get out of cell. The column in second row should be just wider a bit

Comment: I can't reproduce either. The fiddle is fine.