# Prevent grid area from expanding causing whole page to scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm using the following grid layout:

```
grid-template-columns: 10em 1fr 10em;
grid-template-rows: 2em 1fr 2em;
```

To create a centered area that fills most of the screen while leaving some padding around it. Inside this `1fr x 1fr` grid area is a `pane` div which contains an `editor` div which contains a `content` div.

The `content` div can be any height, and the `editor` div has `overflow: scroll` set. My problem is that instead of `pane` staying the same size and `editor` handling the overflow, `pane` grows and causes the whole page to scroll.

I can keep `pane` from growing by setting its `overflow: scroll`, but this causes the editor itself to scroll, rather than its content. This is unacceptable because the editor has buttons which must always be on screen.

Is there a way, within grid layout, to allow this functionality? I originally had it working with a flex layout, where the `pane` div was a single item within a `100% x 100%` flexbox. I switched to grid to allow me to easily resize side-menus, so implementing this without grid is not preferable.

Also, multi-browser support would be amazing, but my target browser is Chrome.

[Here's a jsfiddle with my reproducing my problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/aqd8vrtf/2/)

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#site {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10em 1fr 10em;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr 2em;
  grid-template-areas:
  'top top top'
  'lpn mid rpn'
  'bot bot bot';
}

#pane {
  grid-area: mid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f;
}

#editor {
  display: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#content {
   height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='site'>
<div id='pane'>
  <div id='editor'>
    <div id='content'>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### `min-width: auto` / `min-height: auto`

Generally speaking, a grid item cannot be smaller than its content. The default minimum size of grid items is `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto`.

This often causes grid items to overflow their grid areas or grid containers. It also prevents scrollbars from rendering on the items, since an overflow condition can't be triggered (the grid item just keeps expanding).

To override this default (and allow grid items to shrink past their content size) you can use `min-width: 0`, `min-height: 0` or `overflow` with any value other than `visible`.

This behavior, with references to official documentation, is explained in this post:

- [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276)

---

### `1fr`

Another thing to note is that `1fr` means `minmax(auto, 1fr)`. This means, again, that the track to which it is applied cannot shrink below the content size (i.e., the *min* value in the `minmax()` function is `auto`, meaning content-based).

Therefore, to override this setting, use `minmax(0, 1fr)` instead of `1fr`.

More details here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1777

---

**revised demo (tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge)**

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#site {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  
  display: grid;

  /* grid-template-rows: 10em 1fr 10em; */
  grid-template-rows: 10em minmax(0, 1fr) 10em; /* new */

  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr 2em;
  grid-template-areas:
  'top top top'
  'lpn mid rpn'
  'bot bot bot';
}

#pane {
  grid-area: mid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f;
  overflow: auto; /* new */
}

#editor {
  /* display: relative; */
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

#content {
   height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='site'>
  <div id='pane'>
    <div id='editor'>
      <div id='content'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aqd8vrtf/6/)

Comment: hey mike, neither `min-width: 0` and or `overflow: auto` seem to work in **Chrome** with an implicit grid, `display: grid`?? :/

Comment: @BugWhisperer, post a fiddle or codepen that shows the problem. Or post a new question. LMK

Comment: i found out that it was the width of an input element that was interfering. any idea how to make an input element behave like `width: auto` other than measuring an identical element off screen?

Comment: You saved me! `minmax(0, 1fr)` is the point and no one points it!

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're asking.  I added a wrapper to content to make it scrollable, and set a vh height on it, which you could adjust.

```
#content-scroll {
   height: 40vh;
   overflow: scroll;
}
#content {
   height: 2000px;
}

<div id='site'>
<div id='pane'>
  <div id='editor'>
  <div id='content-scroll'>
    <div id='content'>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16owL8x0/