# grid column gap without resizing the grid

Tags: html, css

```css
.grid{
display:grid;
height:100vh;
grid-template-columns:20% 60% 20%;
grid-column-gap:14px;
}

.grid div{
background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
<div class='col'></div>
<div class='col'></div>
<div class='col'></div>
</div>
```

How to get the above columns gap (14px) without the bottom scrollbar, i.e. without resizing the grid?

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 60% 1fr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used `%` to define `grid-template-columns`, meanwhile `20%` + `60%` + `20%` is already `100%`. So if there's `gap`, the **grid content**'s width adds up will be larger than the **grid itself**, which occurs [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), leads to the scroll bar that you saw.

The solution is to use the [`fr` unit](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/) instead of `%`

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  height:100vh;
  grid-template-columns:20fr 60fr 20fr;
  /* grid-template-columns:1fr 3fr 1fr; do the same at the above*/ 
  grid-column-gap:14px;
}

.grid div{
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='col'></div>
  <div class='col'></div>
  <div class='col'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @qadenza I misunderstood the question. Edited it, use `fr` instead of `%`. Do you need an explanation I'll add the explanation on the answer.

Comment: `width: 50%` doesn't really solve anything as it just lowers the width, if you add a border you will that content is still spilling out,`overflow-x: hidden` as will if there's content it will be cut off

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully that he said `without resizing the grid`

Comment: you should not edit your answer to inlcude details from other answers. You defeat the pupose of having multiple answers and you make the other ones look like a *copy paste*

Comment: I don't think anyone would think @Zohir Salak's answer is copied from mine, I included `checkout @Zohir Salak's answer below`. Somebody has a habit of only reading the accepted answer, especially when the accepted answer is already the correct one. I just wanted to include a useful *(yet with citation)* information in mine to make it better. Anyway, I'll remove it because seemingly it *against the community purpose*.

Answer (score 4):

Grid and Flex apply a minimum width equal to content, in flex we can target it with min-width property on the flex item, but when it comes to grid we can't do that directly on the element because grid establishes columns of which we put elements in, and so we need to use `minmax()` becuase it operates at the grid level

```css
/* cosmetics */
body * {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* End cosmetics */


.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: minmax( 0, 20%) minmax( 0, 60%) minmax( 0, 20%);
  grid-column-gap: 14px;
}

.grid div {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='col'></div>
  <div class='col'></div>
  <div class='col'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: we can control `min-width` on grid items like we do with flex items (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314/8620333).

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's weird when i tried it didn't have an effect

Comment: @TemaniAfif i think i get it, `minmax()` operates at the grid level that's what is needed to resize the column.

Comment: because in this case we are explicitely setting the width using percentage value so min-width constraint play no role. It's only considered when using fraction unit (fr). Exactly like flexbox when flex-grow is involved but if you set the width of flex item explicitely you won't have any issue with min-width.

Comment: Pretty nice trick!

Comment: If you need to repeat this for N columns of *equal width*, use `repeat(N, calc(100%/N))`