# Inline SVG only scaling to parent container in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, css-grid

---

edit: applying `min-height: 0;` to `.svg-container` fixes the container sizes but in Edge the svg elements overflow their containers.

[image: Edge the svg elements overflow their containers]

---

I am trying to make an inline SVG element scale to the height of its parent container. The parent container is sized using CSS grid (I have also tried flex box).

I have been able to get this working as desired when viewing in Google Chrome by setting the elements `max-height` property to `100%`. However when viewed in other browsers the SVG seems to ignore this rule.

These are the browsers I have tried:

- Google Chrome: Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) - **this one works**
- Microsoft Edge: 44.18362.449.0
- Firefox Developer Edition: 73.0b12 (64-bit)
- Firefox: 72.0.2 (64-bit)

Here is what it looks like in Google Chrome (desired result):
[image: Google Chrome]

Here is what it looks like in FFDE (also in regular FF & Edge):
[image: FFDE]

The `body` and `html` elements both have a rule of `height: 100vh;` and all other child sizes are derived from `%` or `fr`.

I would very much appreciate any guidance as to how to ensure the  elements do not exceed 100% of their parent containers when the containers when using css grid or flex as so far none of the solutions I have found in other threads have worked for me.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Senipah/gfr37o2j/) and below I will include the code. Thank you for your time.

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 3fr;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 540px;
    }
    
    .svg-container {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="svg-container">
          <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
            <path
              d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
          </svg>
    
        </div>
        <div class="svg-container">
          <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
            <path
              d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="svg-container">
          <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
            <path
              d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: you need `min-height: 0;` to the SVG container. This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif This solves the problem on FF but not on Edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `min-height:0` to fix the issue in most of the browser (related: [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/8620333)) and for Edge you will need to add `height:0;min-height:100%` to the SVG. The last fix will remove the usage of percentage value with height which is creating an issue with Edge.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 3fr;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
}

.svg-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
            <path
              d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
          </svg>

    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
            <path
              d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
          </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
            <path
              d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
          </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about number of svg containers, then the below works for both Firefox and Chrome

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg-container:nth-child(1) {
  height: calc(100% / 6);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.svg-container:nth-child(2) {
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.svg-container:nth-child(3) {
  height: calc(100% / 2);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
        <path
          d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
      </svg>

    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
        <path
          d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
        <path
          d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The SVG in this example are now effectively scaling to a parent with fixed height. My issue is with scaling when parent containers height is set by %

Comment: What height do you want then? @Senipah

Comment: In the original example 1st child is 1/6 second 2/6 and third is 3/6 of 100vh. Your calc will make each 1/3 of 100vh. Calc is effectively calculating a fixed size. Is there no way make the SVG responsive to the parent container without it having a fixed size?

Comment: @Senipah Updated my answer.

Comment: Appreciate it but I would like to be able to resolve this using grid or flex rather than intrinsically calculating ratios as this would ultimately be used by some unknown number of components.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly the effect you're trying to achieve, but I've set about paring down the markup and the styling and seeing if I can achieve what you're looking for with a single parent `<div>` container and 3 `<svg>` children.

**Working Example:**

```css
.svg-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 60vw;
height: 100vh;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
    
svg {
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
    
svg:nth-of-type(1) {
height: calc(100% / 6 * 1);
}

svg:nth-of-type(2) {
height: calc(100% / 6 * 2);
}

svg:nth-of-type(3) {
height: calc(100% / 6 * 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
<svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
<path d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
</svg>

<svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
<path d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
</svg>

<svg viewBox='0 0 3.904897 29.412678' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
<path d='M 0,25.550255 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 25.550255 H 0 m 2.850575,3.862422 H 2.551199 C 1.142257,29.412677 0,27.979719 0,26.211588 v -0.661333 h 2.01753 v 0.981485 c 0.0024,0.884983 0.574154,1.599169 1.2756,1.593463 h 0.611767 v 1.287474 z M 2.850575,0 H 2.5512 C 1.142257,0 0,1.4329586 0,3.2010897 V 3.8624222 H 2.01753 V 2.8809378 C 2.01993,1.9959549 2.591684,1.2817684 3.29313,1.2874741 H 3.904897 V 0 Z' />
</svg>

</div>
```