# Prevent CSS grid child from expanding parent

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following css

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 20%;
}

.two {
  background: red;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 64px minmax(0, 1fr) 58px;
}

.five {
  background: orange;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.four {
  background: green;
}

.size {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="four"></div>
    <div class="five"></div>
    <div class="six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now as you can see from https://codepen.io/dubcanada/pen/ZEbYBex the side bar if five is taller then three - 122px (64 + 58px) it expands the height of three to accommodate. I want it to add a scroll bar and not expand the height.

I've tried the `min-height: 0;, max-height: 0; min-width: 0; max-width: 0;` tricks and everything I can think of I am not sure how to get this fixed.

Any ideas?

Comment: set a fixed height and or width to the parent and then add overflow:auto.

Comment: @jgetner I am not sure I follow what you are saying? Add a fixed height or width to three and then overflow auto?

Answer (score 2):

You will need an extra wrapper for this:

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.one {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 20%;
}

.two {
  background: red;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 64px minmax(0, 1fr) 58px;
  min-height:0; /* added this too */
}

.five {
  background: orange;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.five >div {
  height: 800px;
}

.four {
  background: green;
}

.size {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="four"></div>
    <div class="five"><div></div></div>
    <div class="six"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve  ...

This is my best guess:

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 20%;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.two {
  background: red;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 64px minmax(0, 1fr) 58px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.five {
  background: orange;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.four {
  background: green;
}

.size {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">2
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="four">4</div>
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="six">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something important in your code. Here's what you have:

```
.five {
  background: orange;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

<div class="three">
   <div class="four"></div>
   <div class="five"></div>
   <div class="six"></div>
</div>
```

The [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property defines the behavior of an element when *its content* is too big to fit.

Therefore, your current set-up won't work because `.five` contains no content, and `overflow` never goes into effect. Apply the `height: 800px` to the content of `.five`.

Also, keep in mind that, by default, [grid items cannot be smaller than their content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276). That's why you have the scrollbar on the higher level container. You can override this default with `min-height: 0` on `.three`, which is a grid item in `.one`.