# Swiper nested inside display:grid css

Tags: swiper.js

I'm battling the calculated width, with swiperjs.

I have have my slider working, however I'm trying to place it inside a container I created with CSS grid that has 2 columns, and 2 rows where the swiper is going into the 2nd row and it spans two columns.   However the width calculations are astronomically large.  I happen to notice that it's calculation also gets bigger if I resize the window.

nothing to special with my settings either... like I said it works when it's not in my row.

https://codepen.io/Johndgraham/pen/VwvmmZL

Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,

  // init: false,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true
  },
  breakpoints: {
    576: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 40
    },
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I came across the same issue and I've fixed by setting `min-width: 0` to the grid items.

I've found the solution on this thread: [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items)

Comment: Tthis worked for me. The issue was only showing up in chrome/vivaldi and was because the parent had CSS grid. Simply apply min-width: 0 to child div's and you are good!

Comment: Dumn!!! Thanks! I lost 2 hours ....

Comment: Works like a charm, can sb explain?  This is one of the things where i feel like you have to have read the html standard docs for...

Answer (score 3):

I resolved sizing issues with Swiper inside grid by setting `.swiper-container` and `.swiper-wrapper` to have `display: inherit;`

I also set `.swiper-slide` to have `display: inherit; width: auto !important; max-width: 100% !important`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the placement of my css grid to work around this, and now have it working nested.

I may take some time later to test out if it's the CSS grid that was causing the issue.