# How to ellipsis content in grid layout auto-width container cell?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

There is a div with grid layout and fixed width.

One of its children is a container and has auto width through template.

Inside the container, here is the content I would like to make ellipsis.

It seems the container's width is incorrect, it does not equal to `300px - 30px - 50px`. How can I change this?

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-layout {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px auto 50px;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.ellipsis-container {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="ellipsis-container">
    <div class="ellipsis-content">Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that your question is more towards why the container size isn't 220px as expected. I've provided an [explanation below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707793/9060223) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `overflow` to the container works.

---

### Question

However, your question is more directed towards *why doesn't the value of `auto` in my container resolve to `300px-30px-50px`?* It should have been 220px, but why is it extending to 600px+?

---

### Answer

This happens because of `white-space: nowrap`. The text is unable to wrap, causing it to extend its width to a very long value. However, why does the container *also extend* when its child extends? Shouldn't `auto` have resolved to `220px` even when its child extends more than that value? It is because in this case, [`auto` is identical to the value `max-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-auto). This means that the `auto` value will resolve to `max-content`. `max-content` will then resolve to the largest [`max-content contribution`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-max-content) value of that specific column.  What is `max-content contribution` then? It is width value of the "children" of the column which causes the `max-content size` of the container to change (in this case, the container is column). [`max-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#max-content) itself refers to minimum size that is allowed, but **still fitting all the content inside** without overflowing. Your `nowrap` text is very long and its `max-content` size is 600px+. This is why the container resolves to 600px+ too (because `auto` resolves to the **largest** `max-content contribution`).

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-layout {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px auto 50px;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.ellipsis-container {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="ellipsis-container">
    <div class="ellipsis-content">Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why and how `overflow: hidden` resolves this? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure about that. Your best bet would be to read the spec about the algorithm to resolve track sizing. My **personal** hunch says that the initial width of the column is resolved to 220px, but then the item inside extends its container size because of that `max-content contribution` spec (try emptying the content div and use JS to inject the long content after a delay [remove the overflow on the item]). Also, you might want to read (on a different perspective) about why content can extend a grid item [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314/9060223).

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow` to container `.ellipsis-container` also.

```
.ellipsis-container {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-layout {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px auto 50px;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.ellipsis-container {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.ellipsis-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="ellipsis-container">
    <div class="ellipsis-content">Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```