# How to get scrolling in a CSS grid?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, css-grid, display

I have a component embedded in a css-grid.

In stack blitz I have an external grid of 3 rows. The one of the rows has a min-width.  How do I get it to scroll horizontally if the viewport is smaller than the min-width?

Within the middle row I have a component that itself uses a 2 column grid. The divs in the columns have a min-height.

What I am looking for is if the viewport is sized so that the entire inner component (red boxes) is not visible, the red box is scrollable.

here is a stack blitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4geyk

Here is another example:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2em 1fr 1px;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  height: 20em;
}

.my-panel {
  border: 1 green solid;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.my-component {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  border: green solid 1px;
  padding: 4px;
}

main {
  border: blue solid 1px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main div {
  border: red solid 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  border-bottom: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header>
    <div>Component Showcase</div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div>
      <section class="my-component">
        <div class="my-panel">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="my-panel">&nbsp;</div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're encountering **two main problems** with the layout:

**First**, by default, a grid item cannot be smaller than its content. The defaults are `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto`. Therefore, the `main` element, which is a grid item in `app-root`, needs an override.

Add `min-width: 0` to `main`.

More complete explanation here: [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276)

---

**Second**, you have both columns with the red boxes set to:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
```

This means that each column will share an equal distribution of the free space in the container. Without any content in those columns, both columns can simply shrink to 0 width, never triggering an overflow. Hence, no scrollbar.

The same problem would exist if you did this:

```
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%
```

So, unless there will always be content in those columns to force a minimum width, I would recommend something like this:

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(250px, 1fr) minmax(250px, 1fr)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ortstl?file=src/styles.css

Answer (score 12):

```css
.the_div_you_want_to_scroll {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-auto-rows: 25%; /* play with this to change height of the children, 50% will fill half */
    grid-template-columns: unset; /* do not set template columns and rows */
    grid-template-rows: unset;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

***This way you can add as many children as you need, In grid system, always hard to maintain dynamic content when using template,***

*when you can't predict how many items are you going to get, use grid-auto-flow*

✌

Comment: For me, children elements are flowing out of `the_div_you_want_to_scroll` and out of the screen with no scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Add max-height:100% to parent

```
 <div style="background-color:yellow;max-height:100%;overflow:auto">
         <div style="height:2000px;">

         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for it

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

<section class="card-container">
 <div class="card">Card 1</div>
 <div class="card">Card 2</div>
 <div class="card">Card 1</div>
 <div class="card">Card 2</div>
 <div class="card">Card 1</div>
 <div class="card">Card 2</div>
</section>
```