# Prevent CSS grid from causing overflow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid, but I'm finding that the grid rows are not all fitting onto the page - instead, they're causing an overflow. How can I resize the grid rows so that they don't overflow the page? I thought the `1fr` value was supposed to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working in my code.

I've had a look at [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items) and tried the suggested answers there (such as changing `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr)` to `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));` but to no avail.

I've tried adding `height: 100%` to the grid and it's container, but it is still overflowing.

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4g9b2qkL/

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  height: 100%;
}

#results {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <p>
      Some stuff on the left....
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>
    <div id="results">
      <div class="result">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Paracas_National_Reserve%2C_Ica%2C_Peru-3April2011.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        Result 2
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        Result 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to consider:

### *missing height reference*

Using a percentage value to set the height of the `img` is problematic because there is no defined height on the container. Generally speaking, percentage heights should have a height reference on the parent for reliable rendering. Your declarations may or may not be ignored / misinterpreted.

See: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

---

### *`height: 100%`*

Setting the `#results` element to `height: 100%` is problematic, if you want to prevent a vertical overflow, because it doesn't factor in the height of the sibling (the `h1`).

```
height: 100% + height of h1 title > height of container (resulting in an overflow)
```

---

### *use a flexible height instead*

Instead of using a percentage height, set a more flexible height, such as `flex-grow`. This tells the container to simply consume remaining space.

---

### *override the minimum height default*

Grid and flex items are set by default to stop shrinking at the size of their content. Override that setting with `min-height: 0`.

See: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

### *cross browser compatibility*

Chrome can do the layout with less code (than posted below). It makes more assumptions about an author's intentions. Firefox, Edge and Safari assume less, so require more rules.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

#left {
  background: lightblue;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

#results {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.result {
  min-height: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Some stuff on the left....</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="results">
      <div class="result">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Paracas_National_Reserve%2C_Ica%2C_Peru-3April2011.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="result">Result 2</div>
      <div class="result">Result 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider [`min-height:0` in different places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314/8620333) and make some adjustment like below:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: lightblue;
  /*height: 100%; removed */
}

#right {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  /*height: 100%; removed */
  min-height:0; /* here */
  /* added */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  /**/
}

#results {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /*height: 100%; removed */
  flex-grow:1; /* added */
  min-height:0 /* here */
}
.result {
  min-height:0 /* here */
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <p>
      Some stuff on the left....
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>
    <div id="results">
      <div class="result">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Paracas_National_Reserve%2C_Ica%2C_Peru-3April2011.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        Result 2
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        Result 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```