# Why does this CSS Grid child need a max-height to enable scrolling?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout with a fixed header and footer, and in-between a scrollable content area. See my working prototype: https://codepen.io/tomsoderlund/pen/ZEOzOdX

When implementing this in my live app, I’m struggling to prevent the scrollable area to overflow, without resorting to using `height`/`max-height`.

See this JSFiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/tomsoderlund/zfyp76kb/

`.messagelist` is the scrollable area. It’s height should be set by its parent `.messagelist-and-form` which has `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;`. The header and footer should always be visible, but `.messagelist` expands too much.

### Update

Even this *nested* CSS Grid prototype works fine: https://codepen.io/tomsoderlund/pen/xxOKWWP

### Update 2: DOM hierarchy explained

- `body` (absolute, top/bottom: 0)
- `.frames` (height: 100%)
- `main` (height: 100%)
- `article.conversation` (height: 100%)
- `.messages-and-quote` (height: 100%)
- `.messagelist-and-form` (height: 100%)
- `.messagelist` (height: 100% **adding an absolute height here enables proper scrolling**)

Comment: overflow always need a fixed height or max-height .. the default behavior is to fit the content so you have to restrict the height if you want a scrollbar.

Comment: @Temani But check my prototype, it’s not using max-height/height.

Comment: if you talk about the codepen, there is a height:100%. IF you talk about the JS there is no height/max-height and no scrollbar too

Comment: @TemaniAfif There's a height `100%` on the `body` and the container `.layout` in the prototype, is this what you mean? There’s no height on the `article`.

Comment: yes, the one on the .layout is enough. The article has its height defined with the template-row which is also inside .layout

Comment: @TemaniAfif See my updated post with DOM hierarchy. All the nodes have `height: 100%` just as in the prototype. What is the difference? I added height:100% to `.messagelist` but it makes no difference.

Comment: You are missing min-height:0 to `messages-and-quote` and its inner div

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you! Adding `min-height: 0;` to `.messages-and-quote` and child `.messagelist-and-form` fixed the problem. Apparently related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items