# Make a DIV fill a Grid Fraction

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[This is what i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Jxp.png)

I want the body to always be 100vw and 100vh (the footer is always at the bottom of the screen and the header is always at the top, all the content is in the middle).

I set the page to display: grid; and grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
The header and footer are 50px, and the content inside is 1fr.

I also set the content to display: grid; and grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
The searchbar at the top is 50px.

Now i want to have the table fill up the rest of the space to the footer and scroll the table once there is enough data. When i set the div height to 100%, it pushes the footer down, i don't want that.

EDIT:
This is an example when i set the height of the div containing the table to 300px (for example) height. (everything works as i want it to, but i want the height to fill the rest of the container)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;

        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
      }

      h1, h2{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      td, th{
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .header{
        background-color: lightblue;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 50px 1fr;
      }

      .topMenu{
        background-color: palegreen;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .data{
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      .footer{
        background-color: lightgreen;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topMenu"><h2>TOP MENU</h2></div>
      <div class="data">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>COLUMN 1</th>
            <th>COLUMN 2</th>
            <th>COLUMN 3</th>
            <th>COLUMN 4</th>
            <th>COLUMN 5</th>
            <th>COLUMN 6</th>
            <th>COLUMN 7</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><h1>FOOTER</h1></div>
</html>
```

But when i set the height of DATA to 100%, it extends the page, and the table doesnt scroll vertically anymore.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;

        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
      }

      h1, h2{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      td, th{
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .header{
        background-color: lightblue;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 50px 1fr;
      }

      .topMenu{
        background-color: palegreen;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .data{
        height: 600px;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      .footer{
        background-color: lightgreen;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topMenu"><h2>TOP MENU</h2></div>
      <div class="data">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>COLUMN 1</th>
            <th>COLUMN 2</th>
            <th>COLUMN 3</th>
            <th>COLUMN 4</th>
            <th>COLUMN 5</th>
            <th>COLUMN 6</th>
            <th>COLUMN 7</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><h1>FOOTER</h1></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS, so we can see what goes wrong if you really need help  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please share your codes so that we can find what's going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: min-height:0; to .container and remove height from data (duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/8620333)