# Make image take all remaining space on page without creating a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm expecting my image to take all remaining space on space without creating a scrollbar, but still it makes page scrollable.

Why image still takes as much height as it needs, despite I said that wrapper size is `100vh`, second row is `1fr` and height of image is `100%` (which should mean that it size should be `100%` of parents size and parent size is literally `100vh` - navbar size).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.reader {
  height: 100%
}

.image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar">NavBar</nav>
  <div class="reader">
    <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/870/1265" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like using it as a background image would give you better control

Comment: @JohnTyner Backgorund image seems like a hack, not the solution of the problem

Comment: Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items
Set the ```min-height: 0``` , as by default it is ```min-height: auto;```. This will work.
https://jsfiddle.net/f9gdr0b1/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to set `oveflow: hidden` to container `div`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.reader {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar">NavBar</nav>
    <div class="reader">
      <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/870/1265" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @AnonAnon I am glad that it helps to you! :)