# How to make a CSS grid item match parent's height like a flexbox item does

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this simple setup:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-child-1">
    <div class="content">
      some long text<br/> here in the child number<br/> 2 some long text<br/> here in the child number 2 some<br/>
      long text here<br/> in the child number some long<br/> text here in the child number 2 some long<br/>
      text here in the<br/> child number 2 some long<br/> text here in the child number<br/> 2 ывавыа ваss<br/>
      text here in the<br/> child number 2 some long<br/> text here in the child number<br/> 2 ывавыа ваss<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-child-2">some text</div>
</div>
```

and styles:

```
  </style>
      .grid-container {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
          border: 1px solid;
          width: 100%;
          height: 200px;
      }
  </style>
```

With this setup, the `grid-child-1` item stretches beyond the parent's 200px height:

[image]

How to make it stretch only as far as the parent's height goes. Similar to flexbox:

[image]

Comment: min-height:0 to grid-child-1

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Are you sure the linked question is a duplicate? It's about content not expanding whereas this is about it overflowing.

Comment: @Lee don't stick to the title, read the whole duplicate (I also gave the fix from the duplicate). Also what  you are saying are the same: "expanding" or "overflowing" both can be explained with the same reason (the default minimum size)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes I read it and don't think it's true to say "This question already has answers here..." but agree to disagree!

Comment: @Lee I gave the answer in the comment (it works) and that answer is within the other question so yes "This question already has answers here ..". It's not about to agree or disagree here. This is how duplicate works.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right in that one can triangulate an answer from them, but imho they're not direct answers to this question.

Comment: @Lee not sure why you want to make it complicated. There is no need to "triangulate" anything. The duplicate is clear and it says: **You can override this behavior by setting grid items to min-width: 0, min-height: 0 or overflow with any value other than visible.**  We cannot have more direct answer than this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I contend that we can! But agree to disagree.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin, yes, that's the point. In the flex example, the child item's height is the same as the container's at 200px, while in the grid example the child item's height is bigger than container's and is equal to the content height at 280px

Comment: Yeah, thanks Max. I was thinking and writing at the same time. I deleted my comment when it made sense to me.

Comment: Looks like @TemaniAfif's suggestion (`min-height: 0`) is the simplest and most efficient solution.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin can you please re-close the question accordingly? People with no CSS activity reopened this when it's a perfect 1000% duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif, there's no edit history. What was the duplicate you proposed?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin the classic one dealing with min-height/min-width: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items  (PS: you can access the edit history using the new icon on the top right under the bookmark icon)

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi, all things considered, your post does appear to be a straightforward duplicate. If you disagree, vote to re-open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the row height in the template:

E.g. `grid-template: 100% / 1fr 1fr;` in place of `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`

```css
#id {
 height: 300px;
}

.grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template: 100% / 1fr 1fr;
      border: 1px solid;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;    
}
      
.grid-child-1 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-container">
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-child-1">
    <div class="content">
      some long text<br/> here in the child number<br/> 2 some long text<br/> here in the child number 2 some<br/>
      long text here<br/> in the child number some long<br/> text here in the child number 2 some long<br/>
      text here in the<br/> child number 2 some long<br/> text here in the child number<br/> 2 ывавыа ваss<br/>
      text here in the<br/> child number 2 some long<br/> text here in the child number<br/> 2 ывавыа ваss<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-child-2">TEST</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

It's also worthwhile to point out, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/1461850) and [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height), that:

> If you have not set an explicit height to the containing block (and
> the child is not absolutely positioned), then your child element with
> percentage height will have nothing to go on and height will be
> determined by content and other properties.

Thanks to [@MichaelBenjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-benjamin) for prompting.

Comment: thanks! Would you be so kind to give a bit of theory behind why/how that works?

Comment: :-) I read around the specification of [`grid`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-container) and [`flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) a bit, but have not yet achieved a succinct explanation. Perhaps the _why_ aspect would be worthy of another question...

Comment: I don't think we need one question for the fix and another question for the why. Both should belong to the same question/answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif fair enough, perhaps you know why?

Comment: This solution is a hack. Although it works here, I wouldn't rely on it for production code, as (1) there's no clear reason why it works, and (2) [using percentage heights without defining the height of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276) is not in conformance with spec rules and, therefore, unstable and unreliable.

Comment: If you do decide to go forward with this solution, perhaps switch from `height: 100%` to `height: 100vh`, or set a height to the grid container and/or parent element.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin, thanks! I used a simplified example. In my code the container does have `height:100%`, so it fills the height of the parent.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Could you link to the spec rules you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: @Lee, I did provide a link. It's in my first comment.