# First grid-column resizing before other columns in 3 column grid layout css

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with attribute `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`

the layout is very simple, creating a 3 column wide and 4 row long grid (12 total divs). Each div is positioned relative with a background set to `url('/img/img.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover`. Within each div I have another div, with a specific class, as an overlay. They are set with `position: relative` and `opacity: 0` so `.class:hover {opacity: 1;}`

Everything seemed to be going smoothly, with my media queries the grid changes to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)` then down to just `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` just fine.

However I just noticed that a bit before the `max-width(900px)` kicks in, the first column of the grid starts to resize, not the other two. I can't seem to get the 3 columns to respond in the same manner whan all 3 have the exact same layout. Any thought would be greatly appreciated.

CSS and HTML of Grid Container and first 4 divs:

```css
.home-catalogue-grid {
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 0.7rem;

        .product {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            aspect-ratio: 1/1 !important    ;
            padding: 1rem;

            &-info {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: $white-transparent;
                color: $darkGray;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                text-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                opacity: 0;
                font-size: 2rem;
                font-family: $title-fonts;
                
                a {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    color: $darkGray;
                }

                &:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="home-catalogue-grid">
            <div class="product pide-1">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <a href="/pide.html">Pide</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product borek-1">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <a href="/borek.html">Börek</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product simit-1">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <a href="/simit.html">Simit</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product baklava-1">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <a href="/baklava.html">Baklava</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the question alone but the most likely cause is that the content is not wrapping/too wide and is therefore forcing the first column to grow when you feel like it shouldn't:

```css
div{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr);
}
p:nth-child(3n+1){background:magenta}
p:nth-child(3n+2){background:yellow}
p:nth-child(3n){background:cyan}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p>
  <p>222</p>
  <p>333</p>
  <p>444</p>
</div>
```

Here is a [CSS Tricks article on grid blowout](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/) and [another similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items) that might help further.

Comment: Thankyou very much for you response! I tried repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr) as mentioned in the second link you provided, and have achieved what I was after. 

Actually, the div growing was not the problem, it as shrinking. I tried to add a screenchot image to my post but wasn't getting it (kind of new to stack overflow)

Thanks again!